# Command line tool for listing ID3 tags under Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, id3

I want to write a script that manipulates ID3 tags of mp3 files. I need a tool that reads the tags and outputs it in a format in a machine-readable format. For example, if I want it to output only the title, then it outputs the title, nothing else. I tried different tools like `id3` or `eyeD3`, but they can only be used to write tags or to output them in a human-readable format. Of course I could just filter that output through `sed`, but it seems unnecessarily complicated to me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use the `exiftool` command from the `libimage-exiftool-perl` package which lets you read (and write) metadata from multimedia files, including mp3s. It can output to a variety of formats including key-value, json, xml and user-defined formats. You can choose to list only specified tags.

```
% exiftool -json 09\ -\ \(Tom\ Waits\)\ -\ Walk\ Away.mp3
[{
  "SourceFile": "09 - (Tom Waits) - Walk Away.mp3",
  "ExifToolVersion": 7.82,
  "FileName": "09 - (Tom Waits) - Walk Away.mp3",
  "Directory": ".",
  "FileSize": "2.5 MB",
  "FileModifyDate": "2008:07:12 13:58:52+01:00",
  "FileType": "MP3",
  "MIMEType": "audio/mpeg",
  "MPEGAudioVersion": 1,
  "AudioLayer": 3,
  "AudioBitrate": 128000,
  "SampleRate": 44100,
  "ChannelMode": "Stereo",
  "MSStereo": "Off",
  "IntensityStereo": "Off",
  "Emphasis": "None",
  "ID3Size": 1678,
  "Title": "Walk Away",
  "Album": "Dead Man Walking",
  "Genre": "OST",
  "Track": 9,
  "Artist": "Tom Waits",
  "Year": "",
  "Comment": "",
  "Duration": "02:42 (approx)"
}]
```

Comment: +1 "sudo port install p5.16-image-exiftool" - gets you going in a mac with MacPorts... Just "exiftool-5.16 /Volumes/MMED/music/Esperanza\ Spalding/Esperanza/02.\ I\ Know\ You\ Know.mp3" and you get all the metadata spit out! Thanks!

Comment: +1 I've just had the same need but for FLAC audio. Worked like a charm. Too bad the program name gives no hint as for the full extent of its possibilities...

Answer (score 9):

`id3info` in [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) outputs the ID3 tags in a format that's dead simple to machine-parse.

Comment: The man page says the following though: Only  ID3 versions 1.0 and 1.1 are supported.

Answer (score 5):

I would look into the [Mutagen tagging library](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen) for Python, which includes a basic scriptable command-line tool, *mid3v2*.  While *mid3v2*'s output is primarily human-readable, the `--list-raw` option may be suitable by itself:

```
$ mid3v2 --list-raw 09_Walk\ Away.mp3
Raw IDv2 tag info for 09_Walk Away.mp3:
TDRC(encoding=3, text=[u'1996'])
TIT2(encoding=3, text=[u'Walk Away'])
TRCK(encoding=3, text=[u'9'])
TPE1(encoding=3, text=[u'Tom Waits'])
TALB(encoding=3, text=[u'Dead Man Walking'])
TCON(encoding=3, text=[u'Soundtrack'])
```

Note this tool only lists ID3 *tags*, not additional attributes of the MP3 file like *exiftool*.  But if you wanted only a particular tag, a simple *grep* for the tagname will grab that for you:

```
$ mid3v2 --list-raw 09_Walk\ Away.mp3 | grep TIT2
TIT2(encoding=3, text=[u'Walk Away'])
```

If *mid3v2* isn't enough for you by itself, and you're comfortable with Python, you could script your own tool to interface with the Mutagen library and read or manipulate the tags directly.

Answer (score 1):

My installation of `eyeD3` came with both the `yaml` and `json` plugins:

```bash
eyeD3 -P yaml *.mp3
eyeD3 -P json *.mp3
```

will do what you'd expect - parsable output to stdout.

The yaml output has better standards compliance as it properly produces a yaml multi-doc (with `---` separators).  The JSON version outputs multi-line JSON, but doesn't wrap the top level in an array, nor have a `,` separating the individual dictionaries.  It's like "line-JSON", but across multiple lines!  I suspect standard libraries may choke trying to parse this :-(